# extracting the details in one form by using a parameter passed to it from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created two Forms in C#. Forms are linked to the database.

In Form 1 I am displaying The list of customer from the table in "ListView" and selecting one among them. The Id of the selected person is passed to the 2nd form through the Constructor.

In Form 2 I am trying to extract the details of the person with the passed Id.

I am trying to read the details("name, phone no, address) into the text boxes of form 2  by using a variable of Execute Reader type.

But the text boxes are not displaying the required data from the table. On Debugging it seems the Control is not going into the While loop.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int id;
    Form2 mainform;
    public Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form callingForm, string x)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
        id = int.Parse(x);//x gets its value from form 1
        MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection();
            cn2.ConnectionString = "Data Source= xyz;InitialCatalog=db1;User = xyz1;Password = one";
            cn2.Open();
            string str2 = "select * from CustomerProfile as p  inner join CustomerTable as c on c.ID = p.ID where ID = " + id;
            SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(str2, cn2);
            SqlDataReader Myread1;
            Myread1 = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show(Myread1[0].ToString());
            while (Myread1.Read())
            {//The data is not getting read here    
                textBox1.Text = Myread1[0].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = Myread1[1].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = Myread1[2].ToString();
            }
        }
        //Myread1.Close();
        catch (Exception err)
        { //rather its displaying these messages.
            textBox1.Text = "Error reading names";
            textBox2.Text = "hi";
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the root cause for my data not showing, but instead the `Error reading names` coming from the try/catch handler?

Comment: I suggest you use parameters for the sqlcommand instead of concatenated strings.

Comment: So what is the state of the Reader???

Comment: I think that problem might be in query - Your tables get aliases and WHERE clause has ID without alias. I think this is not correct because T-SQL don't know which column use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the catch block gets executed, therefore an exception gets thrown somewhere. One for sure is thrown at the following line:

```
MessageBox.Show(Myread1[0].ToString());
```

Because you are attempting to access data before reading it (Read()).

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is failing because it doesn't know to which table the id column belongs that you use in your where clause.

If you [pass on parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) from  your code to a SqlComand do so with [SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string str2 = @"select * 
                from CustomerProfile as p  
                inner join CustomerTable as c on c.ID = p.ID
                where c.ID = @pid"; // notice the c.id here and the parameter
var parmId = new SqlParameter("pid", id);
SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(str2, cn2);
myCommand1.Parameters.Add(parmId);
```

I fixed both issues for you in above code.

You have to call [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) before accessing data so your messagebox before you enter the while loop has to go, that is explained in the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
 // you can't access the reader yet..  
 // MessageBox.Show(Myread1[0].ToString());
```

If exceptions are raised you better show them (or log them):

```
catch (Exception err)
{ //rather its displaying these messages.
     Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
     textBox1.Text = "Error reading names";
     textBox2.Text = err.Message;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I Understood My Mistake